# Send extra info on register

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I am using the default ASP.NET Identity register View, but I also want to pass along the first and last name of a person, how can I pass those variables together with the model that is sent to the controller?

```
@model Test1.Models.RegisterViewModel

<h2>@ViewBag.Title.</h2>

@using (Html.BeginForm("Register", "Account", FormMethod.Post, new { @class = "form-horizontal", role = "form" }))
{
@Html.AntiForgeryToken()
<h4>Create a new account.</h4>
<hr />
@Html.ValidationSummary("", new { @class = "text-danger" })

<div class="form-group">
    @Html.LabelFor(m => m.Email, new { @class = "col-md-2 control-label" })
    <div class="col-md-10">
        @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Email, new { @class = "form-control" })
    </div>
</div>
<div class="form-group">
    @Html.LabelFor(m => m.Password, new { @class = "col-md-2 control-label" })
    <div class="col-md-10">
        @Html.PasswordFor(m => m.Password, new { @class = "form-control" })
    </div>
</div>
<div class="form-group">
    @Html.LabelFor(m => m.ConfirmPassword, new { @class = "col-md-2 control-label" })
    <div class="col-md-10">
        @Html.PasswordFor(m => m.ConfirmPassword, new { @class = "form-control" })
    </div>
</div>
<div class="form-group">
    <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
        <input type="submit" class="btn btn-default" value="Register" />
    </div>
</div>
}
```

Comment: That is pretty basic MVC. Did you try anything? You can do so by adding the appropriate properties to the `RegisterViewModel` and adding their `TextBoxFor()`s.

Comment: I am new to MVC, so I am not sure how to

Comment: Take a look at this msdn blog entry [msdn](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/webdev/archive/2013/10/16/customizing-profile-information-in-asp-net-identity-in-vs-2013-templates.aspx)